# Proving Continuity Of Functions

Tags: calculus

Prove that a function with the property that it takes all the intermediate values between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ for any $a \neq b$ and is a one - one function then prove that $f(x)$ is a continuous function.
$$$$Suppose $f(x)$ is discontinuous at a point $x=c$ the there exists a $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $\delta > 0$ we can find a $x_{\delta}$ in the interval $(c-\delta, c+\delta)$ such that $|f(x_{\delta})-f(c)| \geq \epsilon$ then we have $$f(c)<f(c)+\epsilon<f(x_{\delta})$$ or $$f(x_{\delta})<f(c)-\epsilon<f(c)$$. Now consider $\delta_1 \neq \delta_2$ then as $f(x)$ is a one one function so we have $f(x_{{\delta}_1}) \neq f(x_{{\delta}_2})$, so let us assume that $f(x_{{\delta}_1}) > f(x_{{\delta}_2})$. Also we have $f(x_{{\delta}_1})>f(c)$ so there is a common value say $y$ between both $f(x_{{\delta}_1})$ and $f(c)$ and also between $f(x_{{\delta}_1})$ and $f(x_{{\delta}_2})$ and as the function $f(x)$ follows the intermediate value property so there is a $x_1$ between $x_{{\delta}_1}$ and $x_{{\delta}_2}$ and there exists a $x_2$ between $x_{{\delta}_1}$ and $c$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=y$ which is a contradiction to the one - one property of the given function $f(x)$. So $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=c$.
$$$$ Is My Proof Correct?

Comment: This proof seems perfect. It is a good proof.